# What is the right way to clear select2 dropdown when using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am having an issue with [select2](https://select2.github.io/) where after I enter an item and I want to use the same dropdown again, i can't seem to remove the previously selected item

For example, lets say my id is "#StreamName", I thought this would clear it:

```
 $("#StreamName").val(null).trigger("change");
```

but it still seems to show the previous selected item.  From looking at the html it appears that I have brute force it by doing this:

```
$("#select2-StreamName-container").html("");
```

but that seems like i am not using the API properly so I wanted to see if there is another suggestion or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Working Fiddle - Local Data Source](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/wj0f5sxo/2/)

It looks like the proper way to clear Select2 is what you first suggested as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477163/5357459) suggests.

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#StreamName").select2();
  $("#StreamName").val(null).trigger("change");
});
```

### HTML

```
<select id="StreamName">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

## Update - Remote Data Source

[**JSFiddle Using Remote Data**](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/wj0f5sxo/3/)

This should still work to clear a Select2 input even when using a remote data source:

```
$("#StreamName").val(null).trigger("change");
```

### Full Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#StreamName").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data, params) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
      return markup;
    }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  });


  $("#StreamName").val(null).trigger("change");

  // For testing...
  $('#set-null').click(function() {
    $("#StreamName").val(null).trigger("change");
  });



});


function formatRepo(repo) {
  if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

  var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__avatar'><img src='" + repo.owner.avatar_url + "' /></div>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.full_name + "</div>";

  if (repo.description) {
    markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.description + "</div>";
  }

  markup += "<div class='select2-result-repository__statistics'>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__forks'><i class='fa fa-flash'></i> " + repo.forks_count + " Forks</div>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__stargazers'><i class='fa fa-star'></i> " + repo.stargazers_count + " Stars</div>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-repository__watchers'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> " + repo.watchers_count + " Watchers</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div></div>";

  return markup;
}

function formatRepoSelection(repo) {
  return repo.full_name || repo.text;
}
```

### HTML

```
<select id="StreamName">
  <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: in my case, I am not predefining the list of options upfront.  I am populating from remote data source as per the example on this page: https://select2.github.io/examples.html For some reason, in this usecase, it doesn't seem to clear when doing $("#StreamName").val(null).trigger("change");

Comment: I updated the answer to include a remote data source. Maybe there is something else in your source code that is causing it to fail? Let me know if I can help.

Comment: It's interesting that this method of resetting does not work for me either. Had to sed html('') to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue with

```
$("#StreamName").val(null).trigger("change");
```

Setting the select2 option to blank HTML worked for me.

```
$("#StreamName").html("").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

After change ajax url use

```
$('#StreamName').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: newUri
  }
})
```

You should use

```
$('#StreamName').html('').trigger('change');
```

to instead of

```
$('#StreamName').val(null).trigger('change');
```

to avoid displaying previous text with the same id.