# select2 multipe get error Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I just the following tutorial from official website select2 and get the error and
this is the code

```js
$('.tags').select2({
    multiple: true,
    tags: true
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="form-control tags" name="tags[]">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```

and error in the console like this
[image]

this is javascript code

```
$('.tags').select2({
     theme: 'bootstrap',
     tags: true
})
```

anyone can help me to solve the problem?
<>

Comment: What's your JavaScript code?

Comment: @JackBashford updated

Comment: There are chances that your problem doesn't come from select2 or jquery. Could you post a code snippet (edit your question and click the "<>" icon) with a select2 box ?

Comment: if i running in the snippet its work perfectly @leaf

Comment: Good, now compare both versions (the code snippet and the one with the error) and try to find where they differ (don't forget to check version numbers of the libraries).

Answer (score 0):

> To avoid inifinite loop use trigger method parameters to distinguish event calls, in trigger method usage add parameter and in event callback check if paramater exists, when parameter exists that means that event was triggered from code, if no, that means it is event from ui.

Checkout:
[Select2 trigger("change") creates an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147672/select2-triggerchange-creates-an-infinite-loop)

Comment: It sounds interesting considering the stack trace.

Comment: @BonnyAUlia Same kind of problem : https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2883.

Comment: i dont know how to tell what exactly problem, because nothing diff between select2 and jquery version what i use in snippet and implementation code. The problem show if i try to type something in select2 multiple with log error Maximum call stack size exceeded. and i try to trigger the problem was same. thanks @leaf

Comment: @BonnyAUlia So the problem occurs when you type something (even with the code snippet ?), here is an important piece of information.