# Aurelia + Select2 custom element not propagating selected changed

Tags: binding, jquery-select2, custom-element, aurelia

I have created a custom element in Aurelia.

```
import {bindable, inject, customElement, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
import 'select2';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import {BindingSignaler} from "aurelia-templating-resources";

@customElement('select2')
@inject(Element, BindingSignaler)
export class Select2CustomMultiselect {
    @bindable name = null;    // name/id of custom select
    @bindable selected = null;  // default selected values
    @bindable ({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneWay, attribute:"options"}) source:Array<{id:number, name:any}>= [];   // array of options with id/name properties
    @bindable placeholder = "";
    @bindable allow_clear = true;
    private $select2: $;

    constructor(private element, private signaler:BindingSignaler) {
    }

    attached() {
        let $select = $(this.element).find('select');
        this.$select2 = $select.select2({theme: 'bootstrap', placeholder: this.placeholder});

        // on any change, propagate it to underlying select to trigger two-way bind
        this.$select2.on('change', (event) => {
            if (event.originalEvent) { return; }

            const select2Value = this.$select2.val();
            if(select2Value == this.selected) { return; }

            // dispatch to raw select within the custom element
            var notice = new Event('change', {bubbles: true});
            event.target.dispatchEvent(notice);
        });

        this.$select2.val(this.selected);//.trigger('change');
    }

    selectedChanged(newValue,oldValue){
        console.log(newValue);
    }

    detached() {
        $(this.element).find('select').select2('destroy');
    }
}
```

And it's template:

```
<template>
    <select value.two-way="selected" name.one-way="name" id.one-way="name" class="form-control"  data-allow-clear.one-way="allow_clear" size="1">
        <option></option>
        <option repeat.for="src of source" model.bind="src.id">${src.name & t}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

I use the control like this:

```
<select2 name="payingBy" selected.two-way="model.countryId & validate" options.bind="countries" placeholder="${'Select' & t}" allow_clear="true"></select2>
```

And model is:

```
countries:Array<{id:number, name:string}> = [{id:1, name:"USA"}, {id:2, name:Canada'}];
model.countryId: number;
```

Now, everything works fine if I change the select and on initial binding.
But if i change the model.countryId from ie. 1 to 2, the change is not reflected in the select control, the control still displays "USA" as like 1 is selected.
Because 'selected' property is bind two-way I would expect it to update the select when it change. But it does not. Why?
What Am I doing wrong?

Please help

Comment: Actually it does update the underlying select but not the Select2

Comment: I also made a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UTHR6f?p=preview

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639951/how-do-i-change-selected-value-of-select2-dropdown-with-jqgrid

Comment: No, this is not connected to Aurelia, but tried it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I implemented it like in this post:[Custom Select2 Aurelia component](https://github.com/Kla3mus/select24aurelia)

And it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks I was searching for a long time for a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using the `data` version which expects an object, but you have set your select to work with the `id` value only. So you should use the `val` to pass the id.

```js
selectedChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    if (this.select2) {
      this.select2.select2({
        val: newValue, // << changed this from data: newValue
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        placeholder: this.placeholder
      });
    }
```

Comment: Ok, changed, but still does not work. I updated the plunker too, so you can see. http://plnkr.co/edit/UTHR6f?p=preview