# jQuery-set dynamic dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown

```
<select id="DropdownId" label="condition " ></select>
```

Below is the code, from where i am **filling values into the dropdown**:

```
var request = $.ajax({'url': '/getDropdownValues'}); 
request.done(function(response) 
{   
    response = JSON.parse(response)
    var processbyList=[]; 
    $.each(response, function(index, element) {
           processbyList.push(element.processby); 
    });
    $("#DropdownId").select2({
            data: processbyList
    });
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
    {
        alert('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
    });
```

I want to set a value inside dropdown. **How can I set the dropdown value using jQuery?**

Here 'responseitem' is the value which i am getting from some ajax call and i want this value to set into the dropdown.

I have tried using

```
1. `document.getElementById("DropdownId").value = responseitem;`

2.  `$('#DropdownId').val(responseitem);`
```

But nothing worked for me. Am I missing something or where I am wrong? How to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

On button click event i am creating a table inside that this dropdown is in one in one column of it.

```
function onButtonClick(){

// to fill values in dropdown
var request = $.ajax({'url': '/getDropdownValues'}); 
request.done(function(response) 
{   
    response = JSON.parse(response)
    var processbyList=[]; 
    $.each(response, function(index, element) {
       processbyList.push(element.processby); 
    });
    $("#DropdownId").select2({
        data: processbyList
    });
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
{
    alert('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
});

//this is again inside an ajax call
var requestRegex =$.ajax({url:'/Info',
                         data:"FieldName="+responseitem[0],
                         processData: true,
                         contentType: "application/json",
                         dataType:    "json",
                         });
requestRegex.done(function(responseRegex) 
{
    var panel=document.createElement("panel");  
    var h = '<div class="panel panel-default" >';
    h += '<div class="panel-heading fixed-panel">';
    h +='<h3 class="panel-title">'+responseitem[0]+'</h3>';
    h +='<span class="pull-right clickable"></span>';
    h += '</div>'; 
    h +='<div class="panel-body">';
    h += '<div class="table-responsive">';
    h +='<table id="' +"albums"+ '" cellspacing="0"  class="table-bordered table-hover specialCollapse>';
    h +='<thead></thead>';
    h +='<tbody id="' +"tbody"+ '">';

    h +='<tr>';
    h +='<td><h4><bold>Process By</bold></h4></td>';
    //h +='<td id="' +"processBy"+ '"><textarea class="form-control" rows="1" style="max-width: 30%;">'+ responseitem[2] + '</textarea></td>';
    h +='<td id="' +"processBy"+ '"><select id="DropdownId"  style="width:200px;" value="' +responseitem[2]+ '" ></select></td>';
    h +='</tr>';

    h +='</tbody>';
    h +='</table>';
    h += '</div></div>';

    panel.innerHTML = h;
    $("#DropdownId").select2();
    $("#DropdownId").val(responseitem[2]).trigger("change");

  });   
  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
  {
    alert('Request is failing: ' + textStatus);
  });
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
 document.getElementById("DropdownId").value=responseitem[2];
```

This is showing correct output in console:

```
document.getElementById("processbyDropdownId").value=responseitem[2];
 >>>"page"
```

But not in the jQuery UI.I dont want to refresh my entire page. I just want to refresh such that only the dropdown value refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you using `select2` plugin, you need to `trigger change event` after set the new value

```
$('#DropdownId').val(responseitem).trigger('change');
```

Obviously, `responseitem` must be one of `#DropdownId`'s items.

You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639951/how-do-i-change-selected-value-of-select2-dropdown-with-jqgrid)

**Update**

As you didn't provide enough info in your question, using [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), I created demo to show you how you can change `select` value after an ajax request (*I used select2 too*):

**HTML**

```
<select style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="1">Leanne Graham</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Ervin Howell</option>
  <option value="3">Clementine Bauch</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("select").select2();

setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
    type: "GET",
    success: function(res) {
      var id = -1;
      for (var i in res) {
        if (res[i].name == "Clementine Bauch") {
          id = res[i].id;
          break;
        }
      }

      $("select").val(id).trigger("change");
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/xdXjMN)

You will see after 1 second the selected value of `select` will be changed to `Clementine Bauch`.

Seems like you updated your question, so, you missing `option` inside `select`, change your code as follow:

```
h += '<td id="' + "processBy" + '"><select id="DropdownId"  style="width:200px;"><option value="' + responseitem[2] + '">"' + responseitem[2] + '"</option></select></td>';
```

Comment: I have tried every answer given in the link provided by you, but none of them worked in my case. 
`$('#DropdownId').val(responseitem).trigger('change');`
`$('#DropdownId').selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);`

`$('#DropdownId').val(responseitem).change(); `

`$('#DropdownId').val(responseitem).trigger('change.select2');`

`$("#DropdownId").select2("data", { id: 1, text: responseitem });`

`$("#DropdownId").select2().select2("val", responseitem);`

`$("#DropdownId").select2();
 $("#DropdownId").val(responseitem).trigger("change");`

These all i have tried :(

Comment: @ujjawlsaini please add `console.log(response)` to `.done` function and put the result in your question, I'm sure about my mentioned solution, I used `select2` before.

Comment: @ujjawlsaini I updated my answer, check the demo on Codepen.

Comment: @ Mehdi Dehghani i tried exactly same solution provided by you, but didn't worked for me. I've edited my question, can you look once, i guess i am missing something .

Comment: @ujjawlsaini Can you provide Codepen or JSFiddle link, so I can test your code? you can use [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) for test data. btw, what is `responseitem`?

Comment: ..`<option value="' + responseitem[2] + '">"' + responseitem[2] + '"</option>`
This is exactly what i was trying to do. Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Glad to help mate, just a quick note, if you can avoid adding `HTML` like that way, use `semantic templating system`, such as http://handlebarsjs.com instead. its powerful and simple to edit and maintenance. happy coding ;)

Comment: @ Mehdi Dehghani sure, will check that out! :)