# Can't change html select selected value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to change the 'selected' attribute of a html option element within a select object using javascript.

I already tried this: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript)

This is what I have:

.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group form-group-default" id="divStateEUA">
   <label>Estado</label>
   <select id="listStateEUA" name="listStateEUA" data-init-plugin="select2" style="width: 100%">
      @foreach (var state in ViewBag.EUAStates)
      {
         <option>@state</option>
      }
     </select>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script>
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
                 CheckState();
    });

   function CheckState() {
     if (selectedText == 'Estados Unidos') {
        var element = document.getElementById('listStateEUA');
        element.value = 'Chicago';
     }
   }
</script>
```

rendered html:

[image]

And still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML code, please?

Comment: Where is `selectedText` defined?

Comment: It looks like you may be using the select2 plugin, which I believe has its own methods for setting the selected value.

Comment: @Gavin selectedText is OK. I put and alert to see if it enters in that 'if'.

Comment: Why aren't you using the HtmlHelper for a dropdown if you're using [tag:asp.net-mvc]?

Comment: @doutriforce I'll update the question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips and how can I achieve what I want if HtmlHelper?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan THANK YOU! Just found the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639951/how-do-i-change-selected-value-of-select2-dropdown-with-jqgrid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change selected value of select2 dropdown with JqGrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639951/how-do-i-change-selected-value-of-select2-dropdown-with-jqgrid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike McCaughan suggested (thank you very much), since I'm using select2 plugin, it have a different way to get and set values.

```
$("#select").select2("val"); //get the value
$("#select").select2("val", "CA"); //set the value
```

Answer found here: [select2 plugin get and set values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639951/how-do-i-change-selected-value-of-select2-dropdown-with-jqgrid)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `value` attribute in the `option` tag of `select`.

Modify your razor code to have `value` attribute in `option` tag, so that you can change the combo-box selection on basis of value :

```
 @foreach (var state in ViewBag.EUAStates)
 {
    <option value="@state">@state</option>
 }
```

and now in your jquery code, you should be able to do :

```
function CheckState() {
     if (selectedText == 'Estados Unidos') {
        $("#listStateEUA").val("Chicago");
     }
   }
```

Comment: debug via dev console in chrome and see the code execution flow, chances are if block is skipped as condition may not evaluate to true

Comment: The condition is true

Answer (score 2):

You must provide a value for the options. Your JS is trying to set the select to the "Chicago" value, but none exists. `<option>Chicago</option>` vs `<option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>`

```js
function CheckState() {
  var element = document.getElementById('listStateEUA');
  element.value = 'chicago';
}

CheckState();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <label>Estado</label>
  <select id="listStateEUA" name="listStateEUA">
    <option value="nevada">nevada</option>
    <option value="chicago">chicago</option>
    <option value="arizona">arizona</option>
  </select>
```