# How can I add (and select) a new option on the client side with django-select2?

Tags: django-forms, jquery-select2

I have a selectable field that uses the django-select2 library. I am currently trying to copy the behaviour of the "add another" functionality present in the admin forms of Django.

I added a "+" icon to my regular form template and opened a popup so that the user can register a new item. This part works, now I wish to select the newly added item automatically once the popup is closed. I cannot seem to add a new option to the selectable, though.

I read the original `dismissAddAnotherPopup()` code and the `select2` docs on that, but appending a `new Option(...)` to the element does not have the desired effect - in fact it adds as many options as I want, but they appear under the select box instead of in the dropdown menu, as if they were completely different things.

I looked at the html result and it seems the `select2` field is not using `<option ...>` for the options rendered with Django, but rather some deeper nested elements for the options.

What is the correct syntax for adding new options in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved it for me was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34734546/5418731):

```
let opt = "<option value=" + myValue + " selected='selected'>" + myValueText + "</option>";
$('#mySelect').html(opt);
$('#mySelect').val(myValue).trigger("change");
```

It looks a bit ugly to just replace the html, but as I mentioned in the question, appending a `new Option(...)` to the element did not work.

Comment: It is still a bit strange where do you set myValue and myValueText. Furthermore I cant seem to find the select2 docs your talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully client side, but might be helpful: you can use the [django-addanother](https://github.com/jonashaag/django-addanother) wrapper, like:

```
widgets = {
    'somefield': AddAnotherWidgetWrapper(Select2Widget, reverse_lazy('somefield_add')),
}
```

This will render a "+" next to the Select2 field; when pressing a popup will be opened which allows to add a new object. Once saved, the Select2Widget will be automatically populated with this newly created object.